# How to secure Elasticsearch's REST API via OAuth2 tokens?

Tags: rest, security, elasticsearch, access-token

In our company, we have an Elasticsearch cluster (ES) and another product (I'll call it DataProvider) that puts data into that cluster. These puts are made by calling the ES's REST API.

Until now, the authentication is done via BasicAuth. I.e. the DataProvider puts a special HTTP header into each request, and the ES somehow validates the provided credentials against a user directory.

Now we'd like to switch the authentication from BasicAuth to OAuth tokens. I.e. we have an identity provider (a keycloak server), and the DataProvider can obtain OAuth2 tokens from it (using the "client credentials" protocol). It can then put the token into the requests sent to ES.

But then we'd have to somehow configure ES so that it validates tokens against the same identity provider.

I searched but could not find any docs or tutorials about it. I now even think that this is not supported by ES and that one has to install some kind of authenticating proxy for that.

Am I right? I'd be glad if someone would prove me wrong and give a docs reference or a short description of how it can be done.

Comment: ES enterprise license can connect with Keycloak directly, but you need to pay them.

Comment: We do have an enterprise license, but I still could not find any information as to how to configure the ES REST API to use a certain keycloak (or some other identity provider). Where do I tell what idenity provider to consult for validating incoming requests (tokens within them)? JWK URL etc?

Comment: if you've got a license then definitely ask support, but you may want https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.1/saml-guide-stack.html

Comment: Thank you for your hint. We'll probably contact the support. I saw the chapter you referenced, but my understanding of it is that it's for GUI, i.e. when a real person is bein authenticated. And: SAML is for XML, and my case here is REST. I'll have to contact the support.

Comment: Hi @fml2, i have the exact case here, did you find the right path for this ? (Authenticating REST api clients via keycloak)

Comment: I think this is the way to go: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/jwt-auth-realm.html. But our ES version is quite old and does not have this feature.